# Need to install Watchman version 4.9.0 on a mac

Tags: macos, installation, version, watchman

These instructions at https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html do not work for mac osx:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git
$ cd watchman
$ git checkout v4.9.0
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install

./autogen.sh...
The error:  
pkg-config appears to be missing (not available to autoconf tools)
please install the pkg-config package for your system.
```

The reason I suspect is that not all the same linux packages are available on a mac. How can I get this working on a mac?

Comment: After running `react-native doctor`, I find myself asking the same question. It outputs
`✖ Watchman - Used for watching changes in the filesystem when in development mode
   - Version found: 2021.09.13.00
   - Version supported: 4.x`
But my version is newer than 4.x bc FB specifically states "Note: binaries are built from master only. We don’t provide binaries for v4.9.0" I wonder if `doctor` flagged a false negative. They don't even use that form of `semver` anymore. So unless there's a specific reason to use 4.9, I'd just grab the latest and move on.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
// autoconf@2.7
brew uninstall autoconf
brew install autoconf@2.6.9
//pass
./autogen.sh
```

Just run ./autogen.sh

Answer (score 0):

I'm on macOS Monterey and the following worked for me:

1. Install watchman from bottled binary package.
2. brew bottle watchman on machine created a bottled package for

   watchman@4.0.9. It generated a tar.gz file.
3. brew install -f filename.tar.gz
4. After you install, you will get a warning saying  this package is not verified and would ask to you move it to bin.
   You can go to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General and grant permission for this to be executed.